# Private content for event participant?

Tags: wordpress, civievent, acl, participants, files

My scenario is quite simple to explain :

When a person register on an event (paid or free), we would like to give him an direct access to private content (by email or by direct redirect) (like documents to download or links ..).

how do you achieve something like that in WP ?

---

Actually i'm thinking of using CIVI custom field in events, then checking in the single event template for the "participant" status.. OR do you think there's another smarter way ?

Answer (score 3):

I would use the CiviRules extension, you could structure it something like - if registered participant of 'X' event, send email of 'X' template.

With this you could just create an email template for each event within Civi with the links you would like them to access and it would automatically send to anyone who registers for the event.

Comment: OK thank you for your input, i will give this extension a try and report. I need something generic because i have 400+ events per year. Your advice make me think at this possible solution : for the email i can insert a dropbox/cloud link in the confirmation email template !?

Comment: Exactly. You would just include the link in whichever email template you want. Note, I have noticed that it works best if you add a short delay (5 minutes) when creating the CiviRule to allow for the system to process everything so that any tokens you use are accurate. Let me know how it goes!

Answer (score 2):

I do this with our community, but we use Drupal and create an "organic group" for each event.  We did some investigating of what it would take to migrate off Drupal and onto Wordpress, and group functionality was one of the difficult points.

In Wordpress, the closest I have found to this is the Group plugin.  You could create a group for each event.  Then you create a page or post for the event, and assign access to that page/post to the group.

You could write some small script to add users to a Group every time they register for an event.  I would be inclined to do this via a nightly script, but you could also use CiviRules to automate creating the group every time a new event is created, and adding users every time they register.

If you name your event page/post as the event ID, you could even automate sending them an e-mail when they register to let them know the URL of the page.  In fact, you could even automate creating the page and assigning access to the group.

Frankly you could automate the entire thing:

- When new event is created:

  - Create new WP group, using event ID in the group name
  - Create new WP page/post, using event ID in the page name
  - Assign access to new page/post to group
- When user registers

  - Add them to group
  - Send them welcome email with private page URL

Someone who is familiar with coding using the Wordpress APIs should be able to do this without too much trouble.  Coding this into a CiviRules rule or two would also be pretty easy.

(Having talked about scripts, I currently do the activities of setting up a new group and adding users who have registered to the group manually.  Depending on your scale, it is not too time consuming.)

Comment: This look interesting. Using Group plugin seems quite smart. I will give this CiviRules a try tomorrow ! Thank you.

Comment: There's a clone of the `civicrm_og_sync` module called "BP Groups CiviCRM Sync" that enables synchronisation between BuddyPress Groups and CiviCRM. https://wordpress.org/plugins/bp-groups-civicrm-sync/

Comment: There's also a plugin called "CiviCRM Groups Sync" which keeps groups provided by the "Groups" plugin in sync with CiviGroups: https://develop.tadpole.cc/plugins/civicrm-groups-sync

Answer (score 2):

Another route to consider - add some custom fields to your Event entity, then you can put the url in to those fields, then you can set up a Sch Reminder that is using a token for the custom field, and bingo, each participant gets sent the links to the right document. Very light/easy solution. but i may still not have quite grasped the requirement :-)

(note you may have to theme (?) so those fields don't show on eg the Event Info page)

Answer (score 1):

Welcome empiguet. I do not use WP so much and I may not quite follow your workflow but I think you would need to do something as follows
- if person registers then add to Smart Group
- if in Smart Group, then set specific WP role (this may need an extra extension, i don't know if WP offers it, i do know Drupal does so an equivalent may exist)
- set up WP user role permissions so person who registers for event can access 'private' content to which you would add your documents.

If you only want them to get specific emails, then 
- make a smart group of participants
- use this as target for mailings using CiviMail

Comment: Thanx for your comment. I see what you mean but if i go this way, i will need a permission per event because participant should see only their documents not other event documents.

Comment: Depends if you are wanting them to access to documents online or if you are sending them out I guess. Laura's suggestion may cover the latter scenario